# Kotlin .removeSurrounding not working to strip aws ARN string

Tags: kotlin

Working on my kotlin app, I receive a string containing the ARN for an S3 Bucket, however I just need the bucket name.

The ARN comes in the format : "arn:aws:s3:::$NAME$/*".

I'm using the kotlin .removeSurrounding function to strip away the beggining arn tag and the ending /*, however it seems that the function is doing absolutely nothing.

Here's the appropriate code.

```
EntityUtils.toString(httpGetRequest(***)!!.entity).removeSurrounding("arn:aws:s3:::","/*")
```

Am I just using the function wrong?

Comment: Seems like your actual string has different prefix or suffix. See the [runnable demo](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/jrmfi6lvsohjpbt2mnh4i27bmv/sne6uiki43tfr2lbac4fpp4fod) where the function is used with your example and works properly. If the receiver string does not start with the prefix or does not end with the suffix, then it is returned unchanged, and this is what seems to happen in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've checked and it definitely matches, printing the result gives `= "arn:aws:s3:::$name$/*"`. Even changing to just using `.removePrefix("arn:aws:s3:::")` is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I was being stupid.

For some reason the string literal itself had quotation marks, so the string was ""arn:aws:s3:::$name$/*"", I had to also strip the extra quotations, hence why the string was not matching the stripSurrounding